# Things to know when replacing WEBrick by Thin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, thin, webrick

I intend to replace **WEBrick** by **Thin** on a Rails 3.2 project because WEBrick handles malformed unescaped URIs badly (*bad URI* error). I know there are config hacks to make WEBrick handle unescaped URIs but just adding `gem 'thin'` to my Gemfile seems so easy that makes me wonder:

- Is there something that could break or go wrong in my apllication if I do that?

BTW: I'm deploying on **Heroku**. If there are specific issues with Thin on Heroku then I would also like to know.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope.. Rails is just that simple! :)

Just make sure you start using:

```
thin start
```

Comment: For rails I'd get in the habit of doing: rails s thin. For production, things like Heroku do bundle exec rails s thin.

Comment: Just made a quick test with Thin and strangely, it solves my bad URI problem in development but not in production with Heroku. And I'm sure Heroku has been restarted using Thin. Any ideas why this could happen?

Comment: Check your production logs to make sure that the server started with thin.

Comment: It is: === web: `bundle exec thin start -R config.ru -e $RAILS_ENV -p $PORT`
web.1: up 2013/02/08 19:37:03 (~ 31m ago)

Answer (score 7):

If you have thin in your Gemfile `rails s` should start with thin. For example, the app I work on has thin in the development group in the Gemfile:

```
rails s
=> Booting Thin
=> Rails 3.2.14 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
```